# c++ private object of another class: initialization and use it to call a function in that class

Tags: c++, class, private

I have two classes `A` and `B`, in which the class `B` looks like

```
B.h

class B
{
 public:
    B();
    virtual ~B();
    void eval(int a, int b);
 private:
    A* APointer;
};
```

and correspondingly I have

```
B.cpp

B::B():APointer(NULL){}
B::~B(){}

void B::eval(int a, int b)
{
   if a == b
      {
      APointer->run(); // run() is a public method defined in class A
      }
}
```

Then the class A is like:

```
A.h

#include "LuaBridge.h"
extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}
using namespace luabridge;

class LuaParser
{
  public:
    LuaParser(lua_State* L);
    virtual ~LuaParser();
    void run();

  private:
    LuaRef mRun;
    LuaRef mStop;
    lua_State* mL;
};
```

And

```
A.cpp

LuaParser::LuaParser(lua_State* L) :mRun(L),mStop(L),mL(L) {}
LuaParser::~LuaParser(){}

void LuaParser::run(){
std::cout<<"This project runs!"<<std::endl;
}
```

The system is complicated and actually I call this eval function in class `C` member function. In that class I define a private member BPointer by `B* BPointer` and in constructor I did `C(B* BPointer = NULL)` and then I simply use `BPointer->eval(a,b)` in a class C member function.

In my `main` code, I define a pointer in class B like `B* BPointer` and I use this pointer to call the method `B::eval` by

```
BPointer -> eval(a, b);
```

However, as I run it step by step in visual studio, at the command line `APointer->run();` I noticed that the `this` pointer is like:

```
Value: 0xcdcdcdcd{APointer=???}
```

And when I tried to run this command, I got an error:

```
Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDD1.
```

Well...I don't know how to solve this problem, what I wanna know is:

1. Is the whole idea (i.e. use a private object to call function of another class in a method of this class) feasible?
2. If this idea is feasible, then how should I modify my code?

Any suggestion or idea would be more than welcome!

Comment: Please provide the initialization code of APointer and BPointer (if there is any)

Comment: You're using uninitialised and invalid pointers. Why so many pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the whole idea (i.e. use a private object to call function of
>   another class in a method of this class) feasible?

Yes, it's pretty common.

> If this idea is feasible, then how should I modify my code?

You need to understand the difference between an object and a pointer. Pointer is an address of memory region which may even be unallocated.

What you have here is two pointers not pointing to any allocated memory, hence there are no objects whose methods you could possibly call.

`BPointer` is unitialized, it contains address of random memory region (or magic number `0xcdcdcdcd` in debug build) which may contain just anything belonging or not belonging to you. Dereferencing it is [undefined behavior](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). To avoid that, you should create `B` object and assign it's pointer to `BPointer`:

```
B *BPointer = new B;
```

After you're done making use of `BPointer`, you should release the memory and call `B`'s destructor by calling

```
delete BPointer;
```

`APointer` is initialized with `NULL` pointer, which means it doesn't point to any memory region. Dereferencing `NULL` is undefined behavior too. Similarly to `BPointer`, it should be initialized with valid object pointer and released later:

```
B::B() : APointer(new A(/* lua state pointer */ NULL)) {}
B::~B() { delete APointer; }
```

---

If you don't necessarily need a pointer, I'd suggest using stack allocation for `B` and store `A` as plain member (not pointer). This way you won't need to bother with pointer initialization and deletion.

B.h

```
class B
{
 public:
    B();
    void eval(int a, int b);
 private:
    A AObject;
};
```

B.cpp

```
B::B() : AObject(/* lua state pointer */ NULL) {}

void B::eval(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == b) 
    {
        AObject.run();
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
// ...
B b;
b.eval()
// ...
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation! But in your answer, in the B.cpp of the last part, should it be AObject.run()? I don't even need to initialize AObject ?

Comment: @gladys0313 You're perfectly right, it should be `AObject.run()`. Edited the answer.

Comment: @gladys0313 If A object has default constructor (that is, without parameters), the default constructor is called implicitly. If A can't be default-constructed (as I can see from your updated question), you still need to pass it parameters in `B::B()` constructor's initializer list.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't get your meaning by `B::B(): AObject(/* lua state pointer */ NULL) {}`, could you kindly instruct how to write this initialization? I tried with `lua_State* L = NULL;` and `B::B(): AObject(L) {}`. It is compiled successfully but when running, I met another problem called  `Access violation reading location 0x0000000F.` This problem seems related with Lua.....

Comment: @gladys0313 It seems that `LuaParser`(a.k.a. `A`) isn't meant to be initialized with NULL `lua_State`. Pass there whatever `LuaParser` considers a valid value. Unfortunately I can't tell much on how this class should be initialized.

Comment: yeah sure, I understand this might be a problem related to Lua itself. Thanks a lot for your clear answer and patient explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize `APointer` data-member with some real object in constructor of class B. It should look something like below,

```
B::B()
{
   this->APointer = new A();
}

B::~B()
{
  delete this->APointer;
  this->APointer = NULL;
}
...
...

int main()    
{
   B* BPointer = new B();

   int x = 5;
   int y = 5;

   BPointer->eval(x, y);
}
```

In code you mentioned above, `APointer` is initialized to `NULL`. I think when `B::eval()` is executed, It will cause some undefined behavior.

It would be good if you can also post code of class A.

Comment: @gladys0313 could you please edit your question to show A.h, A.cpp and main.cpp also ... I think somehow APointer is still not being initialized properly

Answer (score 0):

```
0xcdcdcdcd
```

is the state of allocated, but not yet initialized memory. Did you instantiate your `BPointer` in an appropriate way? For example

```
BPointer = new B();
```

Beyond that your APointer is NULL so you cannot call any methods like

```
APointer->run();
```

before you construct an object of type A and assign it to APointer as well.

Comment: thanks for your idea! My BPointer should be okay since what I put in the function body is a simplified one, I also have some other commands and they go well..But I didn't get it when you say "before you construct an object of type A and assign it to APointer as well." Could you explain more?

Comment: In order to use a pointer (call methods through it) it has to point to some object on which these calls are performed. Your APointer is pointing nowhere (it is NULL) such that you cannot invoke methods on it. What you have to do is store the address of an object inside your APointer. You can do this by either constructing an object on the stack and store its address `A a; APointer = &a;` or construct it in the heap (using new) `APointer = new A();`. After that your APointer stores the address of an actual object.